# Python parse user input the same way as CLI input?

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-interface, parameter-passing, argparse

I'm building a CLI and I just discovered [Fire](https://google.github.io/python-fire/guide/) and it's a wonderful way to pass parameters to a function from the command line. It's very clean and intuitive.

However, one problem I have is I need to perform some actions while the program is still running and values are in memory. So for that I can't use Fire (or at least I don't think I can). But I would like to use something that works the same as Fire. I think that I need to use input() to have users input a string, but then I need to interpret that.

For those not aware of how Fire works, here's how. It turns CLI commands into function parameters and executes with those values.

example

```
command line:

function_name parameter1 parameter2 parameter3 --parameter6_name parameter6

python script:

def function_name(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3=0... parameter6_name='No'):
```

I can think of a few ways I might go about this manually in a crude way, but it would be hard and I don't think I would be able to get it to work exactly right. Is there some existing way to parse like this? I've tried searching around for a few hours but I'm not sure I know the right search terms for this problem. I'd appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction.

edit. Say script is called script.py. I'm aware you can use argparsse to call:

```
script.py param1 param2 --param4_name param4
```

(thought I think Fire is better for this purpose)

What I'm trying to do is not pass the parameters during the command line command to launch the app, but pass the parameters while another python script is running, using something like input(). ex.

```
python3 script.py
Type a search phrase for the option you want: input()
Choose a character to select the option: input()
Type the parameters for a function to call to use with that option: input()

option_func1 param1 param2 --param4_name param4

or 

option_func2 param1 param2 --param4_name param4
```

(then it runs that function with those parameters using values from the initial option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), a module makes it easy to write user-friendly command-line interfaces

Comment: I'm aware of argparse and how it works, but what I'm looking for is something that works while my program is running, not as a parameter to call the program. I made an edit on the OP to explain what I mean. Maybe argparse can do that too, but I'm now aware of how.

Comment: A parser like `argparse` can parse a user provided list strings instead of the standard `sys.argv`.

Comment: @hpaulj oh really? That's perfect. How do I get it to do that?

Comment: The argparse docs have many illustrations of this.  `args = parser.parse_args(avgv)`, where is `argv` is something like `['-f', 'foovalue', '--bar=2']`.  It is also possible to edit the the `sys.argv` list, and use the standard `parser_args()`.  The unit test file, `test_argparse` uses both to test various cases.

Comment: Use `args = parser.parse_args(input_from_user.split())`

Comment: @hpaulj thanks guys. I've now got it working. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!